# É válido converter um array para uma class/struct?

Tags: c++

Embora eu tenha testado não tenho certeza se funcionará sempre :

```
class Val {
public:
    int data[4];
};

int main() {
  int data[4];
  Val* v = reinterpret_cast<Val *>(data);
}
```

Comment: Porque não atribui pura e simplesmente no membro da classe? O que está fazendo tem comportamento indefinido e desnecessário. Na verdade eu não gosto de misturar C com C++, a não ser que seja estritamente necessário para alcançar o objetivo.

Comment: É só por curisosidade. Digamos que eu não tenha acesso a classe/struct (esteja em uma biblioteca)

Comment: Isto não faz sentido, se ela está na biblioteca você tem acesso, se for algo privado é melhor não tentar subverter nada, e se está em uma biblioteca que você não tem acesso você não sabe como fazer isto funcionar direito, sem informação, sem solução. O que você está perguntando é uma coisa, o que está comentando é outra.

Comment: eu so quero saber se aquilo ali dá ou não violação de acesso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rodrigo, a forma mais garantida de sucesso de conversão de array para estrutura é criar um construtor da estrutura e uma operação de atribuição. Assim, você determina como ela é feita e evita problemas. Além disso, quem ler o código vai saber como ocorre a conversão. Segue um exemplo de código.

```
class Val {
    void __construct( int *dataArray ){
        data[0] = dataArray[0] ;
        data[1] = dataArray[1] ;
        data[2] = dataArray[2] ;
        data[3] = dataArray[3] ;
    }
    void __destruct( void ){
    }
public:
    int data[4] ;
    ~Val( void ){
        __destruct() ;
    }
    Val( int *dataArray ){
        __construct(dataArray) ;
    }
    Val& operator=( int *dataArray ){
        __destruct() ;
        __construct(dataArray) ;
        return *this ;
    }
} ;

int main() {
  int data[4] ;
  Val v1=data , v2 ;
  v2 = data ;
}
```

Quanto ao `reinterpret_cast`, isso não é conversão de dados mas sim de ponteiros para ler o código binário dos dados, lendo como se fossem dados de outro tipo. Tenho informação de que isso funciona sim, era como se você criasse um union que trata ponteiro para `int` e ponteiro para estrutura composta de apenas campos de tipo `int`, tipo assim.

```
union Pointer {
    int *dataPointer ;
    Val *valPointer ;
} ;

int main() {
    int data[4] ;
    Val *v ;
    /* v = reinterpret_cast<Val*>(data) ; */ {
        Pointer p ;
        p.dataPointer = data ;
        v = p.valPointer ;
    }
}
```

Alguma dúvida?